# How can I animate the loading process from 0 to 100?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding, android-animation

There is a view that is required on the splash screen.

[image]

Namely loading and there to display loading from 0% to 100% in the form of animation.

I'm trying to do it the following way, but this approach is not very good, how can I do it with a small animation?

Here is my code in fragment right now:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    for (i in 0..100) {
        binding.loadingView.setText("Loading $i %")
    }
}
```

And my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data class="SplashScreenBinding">

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.mandarine.aco.splash.SplashViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loadingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Loading"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="42px"
            tools:text="Loading 43 %" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Q: How can I animate the loading process from 0 to 100?

Comment: That depends on what kind of a loading process you have, is it just an animation of loading for a set amount of time, or do you have a non-UI thread loading something that would report the progress back on the main thread?

Comment: "Here is my code in fragment right now" -- all that will do is show 100%, because you are tying up the main application thread, so only the end number will wind up being rendered. "How can I animate the loading process" -- I do not know what sort of animation you are seeking. If you are simply trying to show all 100 numbers, introduce a slight delay between updates. For example, you could wrap your loop in a coroutine and use `delay(250)` to delay 250 milliseconds between numbers.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Ma3x ideally, of course, to associate this with going to server, but at the moment I think i can limit yourself to just downloading for 2 seconds, say. since my splash takes 2 seconds to load

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, at the moment I get only a finite number. 
I tried to animate using delay, or thread sleep, but unfortunately it didn't work out. 
I get the following error
Suspend function 'animateLoadingProcess' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
can you share an example of how to write correctly?

Comment: You need to launch your `suspend fun` in a coroutine. Since you are in a fragment, `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { animateLoadingProcess() }` probably would suffice. See [the docs on lifecycles and coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines).

Comment: @Morozov If you ever decide to base your loading progress on some background thread that would have to update a progress bar, just open a new question for that specifically because that is a different story - you could go with Coroutines in that case as well, as already suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for now you just need a loading animation that lasts for a set duration and updates a 0 - 100 value on screen, you can use a `ValueAnimator.ofInt`

```
private var valueAnimator: ValueAnimator? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val targetTextView = // ...
    
    valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100).apply {
        addUpdateListener {
            targetTextView.text = "Loading ${it.animatedValue}%"
        }
        interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        duration = 2000
        start()
    }
}

// You need to end the animation in case the view is being
// destroyed before the animation has completed
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    valueAnimator?.end()
    valueAnimator = null
}
```

You can also pause/cancel/end the animation by calling `pause()`, `cancel()` and `end()` on the `valueAnimator` as needed.

Comment: @Morozov I edited the code to end the animation if the view destroy event happens before the animation has completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (currentTime < totalTime) {
                delay(abc)
                runOnUiThread {
                    binding.alphaBtn?.text =
                        "${((currentTime.toFloat() / totalTime) * 100).roundToInt()} % "
                //update your animation here
              }  
                currentTime += 1
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).